# Laravel query on relation table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relation

I have problem with query laravel table.

I have relation like: each user have attachment, and attachment belongs to user. I wrote relation in model.

My question is: how make query if I want to return user with relation attachment but for attachment where level = user level? Even if I make whereHas it's return me all attachment for user. Please help!

Answer (score 5):

If you want find user whos attachments met specific constraints then use `whereHas` method

```
UserModel::whereHas('attachments', function ($attachmentQuery) {
    $attachmentQuery->where('level', 'profile_level');
})->get();
```

If you want from already queried model get specific attachments then write

```
$userModel->attachments()->where('level', 'profile_level')->get();
```

It is impossible to query both UserModel and AttachementModel in single query, it must be at least two queries. Even fancy `UserModel::with('attachments')->get();`, which returns user with all attachments, do internally two queries.

Edit:

I noticed that you can define [relation constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) within `with` method

```
UserModel::with(['attachments' => function ($attachmentQuery) {
    $attachmentQuery->where('level', 'profile_level');
}])->get();
```

So if you want find user whos attachments met specific constraints and eager load that attachments then you can do

```
$queryAttachments = function ($attachmentQuery) {
    $attachmentQuery->where('level', 'profile_level');
};

UserModel::whereHas('attachments', $queryAttachments)
->with(['attachments' => $queryAttachments])->get();
```

Comment: Yep that's right, but I want return User with Attachments but not with all attachments but with attachments where level = profile_level. I hope now it's clear

Comment: OK almost there. But now I have object with attachment only without user info :( I don't know if is there any option to make this from backend? If not I just return user with all his attachment and then in fron-end get specific attachments.

Comment: I don't know what problem you have now. User info is no specified in question.

Comment: I added new way to query relations.

Comment: @MateuszDrost Thanks for this,

Answer (score 0):

When you query model relations you write something like

```
$attachments = $userModel->attachments;
```

which is a shortcut for

```
$attachments = $userModel->attachments()->get();
```

so you can write

```
$attachments = $userModel->attachments()->where('level', 'user')->get();
```

Comment: OK but in this situation I have to get user first. I wanna make one query something like: Profile::with('attachment'). I wanna get object Profile with related data but not all related data but where level = user_level

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with combination of `whereHas` and `with` methods as:

```
Profile::whereHas('attachments', function ($q) {
        $q->where('level', 'user');
    })
    ->with(['attachments', function ($q) {
        $q->where('level', 'user');
    }])
    ->get();
```